# Android & Google Voice - Listening for incoming SMS messages

Tags: android, sms, google-voice

is it possible to listen for incoming SMS messages received via Google Voice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell Google Voice to forward its text messages to phone's SMS. This way your SMS receiver will be called but you also get two notifications.

1. Navigate to Settings/Sync and notifications
2. Check "Text messages"

Answer (score 5):

Google Voice does not have a documented and supported API on Android, AFAIK.